# NSVisualEffectView change takes more than one click to change

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsvisualeffectview

So I have an `NSVisualEffectView` hooked up with a button and some icons. The `material` of this view is originally equal to `NSVisualEffectMaterialDark` in other words, Vibrant Dark.

The following code I wrote is **supposed** to do the following:

1) Detect if the view's material is `NSVisualEffectMaterialDark` or `NSVisualEffectMaterialLight`
2) Change the BOOL `isDark` to YES/NO respectively
3) Change the view's `appearance`, in other words the `material`, from Dark to Light / Light to Dark based on the current view.

The problem is that when I run the app and click the button, `NSVisualEffectView`'s colour changes from a saturated dark to a less one, and not Light as it is supposed to.

*What can I do to fix this problem and prevent it from happening?*

**Note:** the `NSVisualEffectView`'s name is `sideBar`, the button's name is `lightButton` and `isDark` is originally set to `YES`.

Here is my code:

```
    -(IBAction)toggleLighting:(id)sender{
    if (self.sideBar.material == NSVisualEffectMaterialDark){
        _lightButton.title = (@"Dark Mode");
        [_lightButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Dark Mode Icon"]];
        [_lightButton setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Dark Mode Icon (Alt)"]];
        isDark = YES;
        NSLog(@"Changed to Light Theme");
    } else if (self.sideBar.material == NSVisualEffectMaterialLight){
        _lightButton.title = (@"Light Mode");
        [_lightButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Light Mode Icon"]];
        [_lightButton setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Light Mode Icon (Alt)"]];
        isDark = NO;
        NSLog(@"Changed to Dark Theme");
    }

    if (isDark==YES){
        _sideBar.material = NSVisualEffectMaterialLight;
        isDark = NO;
    } else if (isDark==NO) {
        _sideBar.material = NSVisualEffectMaterialDark;
        isDark = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the code I wrote is a little problematic, as expected of course.
The `NSVisualEffectView` has none of the above material it checks for, `NSVisualEffectMaterialDark` nor `NSVisualEffectMaterialLight`, therefore both conditions are false. It seems that it chooses to set the material to a different type of dark so that the materials will finally match and be able to compare them properly.

By stating either material (`NSVisualEffectMaterialDark` nor `NSVisualEffectMaterialLight`), in `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` I was able to fix the issue where I had to click twice for the button to actually work.

**EDIT:**

It turns out there are other materials I wasn't aware of and they happened to be the desired ones.
These are `NSVisualEffectMaterialMediumLight` and `NSVisualEffectMaterialUltraDark`.